# Database cluster for storage

Tags: mysql, mariadb, nosql

I’m currently working in a big project than would need massive database storage and web access.

About web server performances, it look like quite easy to deploy. I would use load balancing system with PROXY HA/VARNISH

My question is for database storage.
I will need to store huge quantity of simple data in real time and generate statistics. I was thinking about nosql but I want to keep it “simple” and I don’t have any knowledge about nosql… I think best choice for me would be to deploy mysql cluster of maybe mariadb cluster.

Let me show you data I will need to store:
I will receive about 1 to 1,5 million of records each day: ip address, username, site id, rating.
Based on those data, I’ll produce statistics every 6 hours. For the first database I’ll have massive write access, and very small read access (read access is only for internal use) For statistics, I would have about 25 millions of read query per day.

Because the database will be very huge after months, I want to always have enough disk space without having to move to new server, I don’t know what kind of technology will be the best. I think I’ll use OVH dedicated server with 2 NIC First for public access and second for internal network so every server can communicate with private low latency high performance network. I need to use soft load balancer because it’s based on dedicated servers.
I would like to have high availability and “unlimited” data storage so I would need something like RAID 15… Maybe RAID1 with 2 dedicated server with real time replication

I really don’t know what would be the best solution and software.
-   Real time write access to 1,5 million of records each day
-   About 25 millions of query per day based on statistics generated 
-   Storage is simple text varchar 50 max.

Answer (score 0):

I find NoSQL far more simple than sql (relationships are easier to setup) but SQL can be better for simple VARCHAR storage, pacemaker can be the solution you are looking for, it's a simple HA/Failover cluster and you can easily setup a mysql cluster with it, it can also setup some loadbalancing and DRBD (RAID 1 over IP).

for the data storage, i think RAID 15 is not the best solution, RAID 5 offers less performance and sometimes some data problems on disk failure, in my company, we are only using a RAID 10 and it's relly enough for our software (about 1 milion NoSQL requests per day).

If you are looking for a NoSQL cluster, Neo4j has a native Cluster system (i never used it, but i know it's really powerfull), maybe mongodb can do it too, but i really don't know, never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to add comments yet, but just wanted to let you know that mongo could be a really viable solution for you.  It scales easily and your cluster will automatically reconfigure itself if you lose the primary node (one of the secondary nodes will be promoted to become the new primary).

Depending on how your data is queried, you may want to look at indexing it in Elastic Search or Solr - these engines are designed specifically for handling large volumes of search queries.

Comment: You're right, I think I'll use mongo (or other nosql) for storing data, and statistics will be stored on mysql for easy queries